# NeoVim: Switch between sets of open tabs, depending on git branch

Tags: vim, git, neovim

When working on multiple different branches in a git repo, I have found myself to want different sets of files opened in different tabs. Is there any plugin or way to essentially "save" the current state of open tabs upon checking out a different branch, and when the original branch is checked out again - that set of tabs is restored? Would ideally be able to keep the tab state of several different branches.

Running multiple instances of NeoVim and managing it by suspending the processes, with some way such that they don't get upset about having the same file open, might be one option.

Comment: A combination of [Git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) and per-tree instances of your editor might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big problem with switching branches in Vim is that buffers, registers, history, etc. are global, which makes building workflows that don't follow that pattern quite difficult. And then there are swap files, persistant undo files, etc. For example, some files may disappear from your filesystem when you switch branch but you would have to remove any reference to them in Vim, which might not be as trivial as it sounds.

A more economical strategy would be to treat each branch as a separate project:

1. use [Git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) to have one "work tree" (read "directory") for each branch,
2. have one editor instance per work tree.

In practice, it would look like this:

```
$ git worktree add ../this-project_some-branch some-branch
$ cd ../some-branch
$ vim .
```

With one terminal emulator tab per "project/work tree/Vim", you should be able to get yourself separate and stable environments.

Comment: Oh yeah this sounds very doable. I'll figure out some workflow with terms / workspaces / etc, but a baseline of treating the branches as separate projects sounds excellent. Thank you very much!